# How to send a variable var from javascript to java app

Tags: java, javascript, json, web, httprequest

I'm working on an application that i need to send a javascript variable value to an java application by js function.
I thought make it changing an local json file, and read it in my java app, but i didn't suceeded.
This parse could be throught HttpRequest method or something like this.
I'm kind lost in this part of the project, and waiting for a answer.
Thank you everybody since now!

Comment: What sort of Java application?  Is this a web application where the JavaScript is running on a page of that application?  If so then look into using AJAX with whatever web application technology you're using.

Comment: Why are you not able to read the JSON through Java? JSON is readable in every programming language. Anyways what you need to do is make a get/post request (either in AJAX or through html form) sending JSON to a piece of Java code server side. To do this asynchronously (without reloading the web page) use AJAX. It's very easily done by using the JQuery library which has built-in get and post request functions.

Comment: [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) Use whichever one you want, these are the easiest ways.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by two way.

1. passing the value by query paramenter
   var formObj =******;
   formObj.action= htttp://localhsot:8089/test/test.jsp?userName="+javascriptvarialbe;
   formObj.submit();
2. by hidden variable
   '<  input type="hidden" name="userName" />'

then in java

String userName = request.getParameter("userName");